# Detecting if Windows Login Screen is visible to user in VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, locking, user32

Hey StackOverflow VB.NET members,

After running the following code (which locks the computer), what code must I be applying to see if the user has successfully logged into the computer and that "Lock Screen" I'd so called has disappeared?

```
Private Declare Function LockWorkStation Lib "user32.dll" () As Long

Private Function LockComputer()
    LockWorkStation()
End Function
```

I will call "LockComputer", after that what do I do to see if the Lock screen so called by this function (after say 2 minutes) has disappeared or is still there asking for the password from the user!

Thanks,
Akshit Soota

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

There it says: There is no function you can call to determine whether the workstation is locked.

But:

To receive notification when the user logs in, use the WTSRegisterSessionNotification function to receive WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE messages. You can use session notifications to track the desktop state so you know whether it is possible to interact with the user.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read this in the [MSDN documentation of LockWorkstation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> There is no function you can call to
>   determine whether the workstation is
>   locked. To receive notification when
>   the user logs in, use the
>   WTSRegisterSessionNotification
>   function to receive
>   WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE messages.