# VBScript - How do I tell if a remote workstation is sitting at the login screen?

Tags: authentication, vbscript, wmi

How do I tell if a remote workstation is sitting at the login screen? I know how to tell if a computer has an active user logged in or not.

If a computer is at the login screen that script would say there is no user logged in. However the "Logged in User" script can also report "No user logged in" while loading startup scripts.

I also don't need to know if the workstation is Locked. Is there any way to determine if a computer is specifically either prompting for login credentials or saying "Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to log in"?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a combination of [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`Win32_LogonSession`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
computer = "..."

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://" & computer & "/root/cimv2")

logonScreenCount = wmi.ExecQuery _
  ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'LogonUI.exe'").Count
interactiveUserCount = wmi.ExecQuery _
  ("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogonSession WHERE LogonType = 2").Count

If logonScreenCount = 1 And interactiveUserCount = 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Logon screen is being displayed"
End If
```

The query against `Win32_Process` checks if the logon screen process is running, the query against `Win32_LogonSession` checks if a user is logged in interactively. Some possible combinations are:

- *logonScreenCount = 0, interactiveUserCount = 0:*
  System has probably not finished booting (no logon screen and no interactive logon).
- *logonScreenCount = 1, interactiveUserCount = 0:*
  System is up, logon screen is being displayed, but no user is logged in.
- *logonScreenCount = 0, interactiveUserCount = 1:*
  System is up, a user is logged in on the console.

Note that repeated queries won't pick up changes. You have to run `GetObject()` again to update the WMI object.

Note also that the above code snippet does not handle errors like the RPC server on a remote host being unavailable during system boot.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the following post 
[Detecting if Windows Login Screen is visible to user in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787359/detecting-if-windows-login-screen-is-visible-to-user-in-vb-net)

I know it isnt quite what your asking, but one of the answers provides a link to an MSDN article outlining WTSRegisterSessionNotification, which may allow you to construct a mechanism which gets you close.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comment Mark, thanks. Those session notifications unfortunately don't have any notification that states "Is at login screen", only when someone logs in or out. Though that post did state there's no way to determine if a computer is locked, which MAY have answered my question right there. The login screen means the computer is effectively locked, though with no logged in user. I'm not giving up quite yet though.

Comment: Sorry it didnt help out more... Good luck :D